# Is it possible to set default generic type?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to restrict type of parameter dynamically, according to another parameter?

```
type Foo = {
    bar: string;
    baz: number;
}

let o: Foo;

function setProperty(key: keyof Foo, value: Foo[keyof Foo]) {
    o[key] = value;
}

setProperty("bar", 55); // shouldn't be allowed
setProperty("bar", "55"); // allowed
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Foo%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20baz%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20o%3A%20Foo%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20setProperty(key%3A%20keyof%20Foo%2C%20value%3A%20Foo%5Bkeyof%20Foo%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20o%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AsetProperty(%22bar%22%2C%2055)%3B%20%2F%2F%20shouldn't%20be%20allowed%0D%0AsetProperty(%22bar%22%2C%20%2255%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20allowed

Comment: Why not generics?

Comment: If it's possible with generics it's fine. I just dont want to do `setProperty<Foo>` from the consumer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html) with generics:

```
type Foo = {
    bar: string;
    baz: number;
}

let o: Foo;    

function setProperty<P extends keyof Foo> (key: P, value: Foo[P]) {
    o[key] = value;
}

setProperty("bar", 55); // Throws error
setProperty("bar", "55"); // allowed
```